# How to implement blue tick feature like Whatsapp in react native chat app

Tags: react-native, socket.io, react-native-gifted-chat

I'm building a chat application which is working fine but now I want to implement `blue tick` feature to check either message has been `seen or not`. I'm using `socket.io` and `react-native-gifted-chat` in this app. I am struggling to find a way to know how to do this. I visit many links but did not get the clear picture. react-native-gifted-chat describes to use `renderTicks` function for this but I'm unable to understand its implementation.

**renderTicks**

```
  renderTicks = (message) => {
    const {currentMessage, renderTicks, user} = this.props;
    if (renderTicks && currentMessage) {
      return renderTicks(currentMessage);
    }
    if (currentMessage && user && currentMessage.user._id !== user._id) {
      return null;
    }
    if (
      currentMessage &&
      (currentMessage.sent || currentMessage.received || currentMessage.pending)
    ) {
      return (
        <View style={styles.content.tickView}>
          {!!currentMessage.sent && (
            <Text style={[styles.content.tick, this.props.tickStyle]}>✓</Text>
          )}
          {!!currentMessage.received && (
            <Text style={[styles.content.tick, this.props.tickStyle]}>✓</Text>
          )}
          {!!currentMessage.pending && (
            <Text style={[styles.content.tick, this.props.tickStyle]}></Text>
          )}
        </View>
      );
    }
    return null;
  };
```

**GiftedChat**

```
<GiftedChat
        ..........
        renderTicks={(message) => this.renderTicks(message)}
/>
```

Here **currentMessage** and **renderTicks** both are coming **undefined**.

What I'm doing wrong here, kindly enlighten.

OR

Can anybody help me out with example code of renderTicks.

**react-native version = 0.62.2**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You need to update the message object from the receivers end, when the receiver opens the chat screen component, you can use a useEffect function that mutates the message object at the server. Like it sets the read property to true. The sockets will automatically notify the sender that the object has changed, and the sender will refetch the chat list, with read property set to true. And gifted chat will show a blue tick.

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue with GiftedChat, not able to change the message states,
read property from socket appeared as undefined.. can you please suggest what could be wrong?